# LDAP search error

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to use LDAP login to ezpublish but I am facing this error -

```
ldap_search() [<a href='function.ldap-search'>function.ldap-search</a>]: Search: Operations error in C:\wamp\www\ezpub\kernel\classes\datatypes\ezuser\ezldapuser.php on line 322
```

I don't know how to fix this or why this error is occuring. This is the debug trace before ldap_search fails -

```
  'LDAPFilter' => '( &(objectCategory=person)(userprincipalname=pavan.reddy@xyz.com))',

 'retrieveAttributes' => 
  array (
    0 => 'userprincipalname',
    1 => '',
    2 => '',
    3 => 'userprincipalname',
  )

  'LDAPSearchScope' => 'sub'

  'LDAPBaseDN' => 'ou=xyz,dc=xy,dc=xyzldap'
```

And, this fails when it hits this line of code -

```
$sr = ldap_search( $ds, $LDAPBaseDN, $LDAPFilter, $retrieveAttributes );
```

What is wrong here? Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be? And how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason it was not working. Turns out that the LDAP server that I was connecting to does not allow anonymous bind, so I had to specify the user name and password to bind to the server (ldap_bind function).

Once I provided the user name and password it started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have empty values in your `$retrieveAttributes`-array?

This might be the problem... Could you try:

```
$retrieveAttributes = array('userprincipalname');
```

Comment: I am using ezpublish - its a opensource cms solution. So, I input these values in the configuration files and it builds these variables based on it. Hence, the empty values. BUt, I have even tried $sr = ldap_search( $ds, $LDAPBaseDN, $LDAPFilter) but that doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you check if the filter actually works, e.g. using some LDAP tool like Apache Directory Studio or the LDAP command line utilities?

Comment: Yes I checked for the same filter in a test app that I had built and it worked fine and it worked fine (but that's using .net)